# No touchpad with acpi=off; can't reboot/turnoff/logout with acpi

Tags: boot, grub2, touchpad

I have a Ubuntu 17 installation and with acpi=off I can turn off/reboot/logout nicely, but the touch pad does not work. Does not even get detected. Without telling GRUB to use acpi=off,  I get the touchpad working but Ubuntu freezes when I turn off/reboot/logout.